# How to write an android app to access and edit contents of a MySQL Database stored in my cPanel of my domain?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, cpanel

I've searched a lot but couldnt find anything that could be useful or easy to understand.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android can't directory manipulate or access MySQL Databases. The easiest solution is to have Android post data to a web server which hosts some PHP scripts. The PHP scripts can then do what is needed in the database, and if returning rows from the database, encode them into JSON and return the JSON content back to android. You can then manipulate the contents of JSON for your app. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ may be of use.

It also means using this method, you don't have to expose your database to the outside world on the internet as the PHP pages will just access the database using Localhost. (Assuming you put the PHP scripts on the server that hosts the database)

Comment: That got me running on my localhost but how do I implement this on my online cpanel??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. cPanel is just a web interface to manage your database. Unless cPanel has some API you can use then you can't manage your db from android via cpanel only via the method I described

Comment: Oh ok my doubt cleared. Thanks a lot! Yes I can store the database on my PC and access it from any Android phone so long as it is programmed according to my localhost server details, right?

Comment: It depends on where the PHP files are stored. Your android app can post to the PHP pages at any location, i.e. www.yourdomain.com/connect_my_db.php. Then if the PHP scripts are hosted on the same server where MySQL is then PHP can connect to MySQL using localhost. There is nothing to stop you though having the PHP files on one server and PHP accessing the db on another server over the internet as long as the mysql database allows external access